# If $X_n=Y_n$ in distribution and $X_n \to 0$ almost surely, then does $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely ? (For particular $X_n$ and $Y_n$)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, limits

Of course in general the answer to my question is NO, however I am interested in two sequences of random variables that have very specific structure.

Let $a_n,b_n$ be deterministic (real-valued) sequences and let $\xi_n$ be an i.i.d sequence of random variables. Then let
$$ X_n=a_n+b_n\xi_n, \quad Y_n=a_n+b_n\xi,$$

where $\xi=\xi_n$ in distribution. If we suppose $X_n \to 0$ almost surely, can we conclude that $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely?

An idea of a possible method of proof (or a counter example) would be much appreciated.

Note we also assume that the sequence $b_n$ is non-degenerate i.e not the zero sequence (otherwise the question would not be very interesting).

Comment: A symmetrization argument shows $b_n \to 0$ (provided $\xi$ is not a constant r.v.) and then it follows that $a_n \to 0$. So the answer is YES.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for the comment, would you mind clarifying what you mean by symmetrization argument ? I'm afraid I'm not familiar, thanks.

Comment: If $(\xi_n')$ is an independent copy of $(\xi_n)$ then $b_n (\xi_n-\xi_n') \to 0$ a.s.

Comment: Is it obvious why that statement is true? Also in this instance it should not be $\xi_n'$ but rather just $\xi'$, for the $Y_n$'s the random variable $\xi$ is the same for each n.

Comment: A remark: the case $X_n\to^P 0\iff Y_n\to^P0$ is simple to prove and does not need independence.

Comment: @Snoop Yes this is true convergence in probability is easy. Convergence of  $X_n$ a.s. yields for all $\epsilon >0$ we have, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq \epsilon)=0$, but as $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq \epsilon)=\mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon)$ for all $n$, taking limits yields the claim. Convergence almost surely however seems a bit tougher than one might initially think! (At least that was my experience)

Comment: @geetha290krm If you would not mind I would very much appreciate it if you could give your thought process in an answer please, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X_n\to0$ a.s. Then, for every $\varepsilon >0$ we have $P(|X_n|>\varepsilon\textrm{ i.o.})=0$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Suppose $P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon\textrm{ i.o.})>0$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon\textrm{ i.o.})>0&\stackrel{\textrm{B-C I}}{\implies} \sum_nP(|Y_n|>\varepsilon)=\infty\\
&\stackrel{\xi_n\sim\xi,\forall n}\implies \sum_nP(|X_n|>\varepsilon)=\infty\\
&\stackrel{\textrm{B-C II}}{\implies}P(|X_n|>\varepsilon\textrm{ i.o.})=1
\end{aligned}$$
But this is a contradiction. Then $P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon\textrm{ i.o.})=0$. We conclude, because $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I guess this means my initial statement in my question that the claim was not true in general is false. As this argument holds in a completely general setting, not utilising the special structure of the random variables I have given. The statement you have proven is , given two sequences of random variables $X_n$,$Y_n$ such that $X_n$ are independent and $X_n=Y_n$ (in distribution) for all $n$, then if $X_n \to 0$ almost surely then $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely. Would you agree?

Comment: Or rather I should say, with the additional assumption of independence of the $X_n$'s, my question as posed in the title is true without any further structure imposed on the random variables in question.

Comment: @Emmet you're welcome. With the key assumption of independence of $(X_n)_n$, this indeed seems to work in general.